# How to get a application window to a different size when starting it?

Tags: windows

When I start explorer, it starts in a reduced window (not minimized but smaller, not in full screen).

How can I get it maximized when I start it ? When I close it, it's already maximized.

In general, how you do it with all applications ?

What I have to do if I want word, excel or anything else started with a half-screen size ?

Answer (score 1):

See the free [Eusing Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm):

> Auto Window Manager automatically
>   manages any window you specify. For
>   instance, some web browsers open up in
>   a non-maximized window. Using Auto
>   Window Manager, you can set those
>   windows to automatically maximize
>   (minimize, normal, minimize to tray,
>   stay on top) every time they opened.
>   It works with almost any program,
>   including web browsers, Notepad, etc.
>   Auto Window Manager stays running in
>   the system tray, so it stays out of
>   your way while it works.

A more feature-rich product is [Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/).
It's shareware at $49.95 with free trial of 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the shortcut to the application, in its Properties there is a setting (Run) that allows you to choose between starting minimized, maximized etc.